# plot_generic() function in plot_roc_components not found in R

Tags: r, roc

I am using `plot_roc_components` function from `rmda` package. The definition of it has plot_generic() function. But, I am not able to find definition of this function. Why is it so?
   The reason for it to see if there is an option for legend.size(). `plot_roc_components` gives me figure, however, I want to change the legend size. There is an option for legend.position, but not for its font size.

Could you please explain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mdbrown/rmda/blob/57553a4cf5b6972176a0603b412260e367147619/R/plot_functions_sub.R

You were looking in one file but it was defined in another file.

```
plot_generic<- function(xx, predictors, value, plotNew,
                        standardize, confidence.intervals,
                        cost.benefit.axis = TRUE, cost.benefits, n.cost.benefits,
                        cost.benefit.xlab, xlab, ylab,
                        col, lty, lwd,
                        xlim, ylim, legend.position,
                        lty.fpr = 2, lty.tpr = 1,
                        tpr.fpr.legend = FALSE,
                        impact.legend = FALSE,
                        impact.legend.2 = FALSE,
                        population.size = 1000,
                        policy = policy, ...){
## xx is output from get_DecisionCurve,
## others are directly from the function call

  #save old par parameters and reset them once the function exits.
  old.par<- par("mar"); on.exit(par(mar = old.par))


  xx.wide <- reshape::cast(xx, thresholds~model, value =  value, add.missing = TRUE, fill = NA)
  xx.wide$thresholds <- as.numeric(as.character(xx.wide$thresholds))

  if(is.numeric(confidence.intervals)){

    val_lower <- paste(value, "lower", sep = "_")
    val_upper <- paste(value, "upper", sep = "_")

    xx.lower <- cast(xx, thresholds~model, value = val_lower, add.missing = TRUE, fill = NA)
    xx.upper <- cast(xx, thresholds~model, value = val_upper, add.missing = TRUE, fill = NA)
    xx.lower$thresholds <- as.numeric(as.character(xx.lower$thresholds))
    xx.upper$thresholds <- as.numeric(as.character(xx.upper$thresholds))
  }


  # adjust margins to add extra x-axis
  if(cost.benefit.axis) par(mar = c(7.5, 4, 3, 2) + 0.1)

  #set default ylim if not provided


#initial call to plot and add gridlines
```